# Unable to implement pgrouting(plugin) pgr_astar routing algorithm (shortest path)

Tags: qgis, postgis, pgrouting

I have been working on a project for indoor navigation.

I made the floorplan of the building and road-map for routing purposes as shp files (using JOSM, making GeoJSON and then converting to shp file using http://www.mapshaper.org/)

Then using POST GIS ShapeFile Loader (of pgAdmin III) I imported road-map(*route.shp)* to the database.

In QGIS, i was able to use the shortest path plugin to do the routing
[image: screen shot of my project, red color indicates the route]

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

EDITED

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
The following are screen shots of **route**
[image: ROUTE IN QGIS DB MANAGER]
[image: contents of ROUTE]
[image: prev]

The following are screen shots of **route_vertices_pgr**
[image]
[image]
[image]

When I tried to use the pgrouting plugin of QGIS , I got the below error
[image: error]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just to clarify: Did you install pgRouting in testgis database?

Comment: Please check if the geometry column is called "geom" or "the_geom" and what you used in the plugin.

Comment: I installed pgRouting using the Plugin Manager of Qgis. I didn't have to select any database during installation. 

Geometry column in route is 'geom'.
Geometry column in topology created is 'the_geom'.
 I tried both.

Comment: Did you install pgrouting for PostGIS? Please note that this has nothing to do with what you did or did not install in QGIS.

Comment: @underdark YES...given below is my output in psql:


`azx=# select pgr_version();
                   pgr_version
-------------------------------------------------
 (2.0.0,pgrouting-2.0.0,0,d6ed2cb,master,1.53.0)
(1 row)`

Comment: I have made my question more clear here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/89038/pgrouting-unexpected-output Thank you underdark and sanak for your response

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the geometry values from input latitude/longitude coordinates via SQL,
please see the following section of pgRouting Workshop contents.

[8. Writing a pl/pgsql Wrapper]
http://workshop.pgrouting.org/chapters/wrapper.html

> I want to pass the latitude and longitude of the source and target as i did in the shortest path plugin of QGIS.
>
> The output i need is the geom value of the route obtained. Any help?

Comment: I was going through the code of the function (section 8.4 - Route between lat/lon points and return ordered geometry with heading) and i found that SRID is being passed as a parameter.

When i loaded the map to database , i set the SRID to be 111 (a random value). So what value should i give here?

How important is SRID?

Comment: Judging from your attached image, I think that any SRID is okay. (4326 .etc)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use pgRouting from within QGIS, you should use the **pgRoutingLayer** plugin from https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/pgRoutingLayer/

Comment: Ok. I installed it. 

I don't have an edge_table for my route.shp

How can i generate one?

Also I get a python error when i try to give source_id or target_id. Honestly, I don't know what they are. Is it the same as gid?

Comment: Could you specify edge_table:route, geometry:geom, id:gid, then select source_id/target_id from green [+] button, and click [Run] button?

Comment: @sanak , i ..tried that . I get a python error

Comment: @xach4u Okay... Could you tell me the error message details?

Comment: [link]http://pastebin.com/nzvMVaq3

Comment: @xachu4u Please update your question and add screenshots of pgAdmin where we can see the tables and of the pgRoutingLayer plugin with the settings you are using.

Comment: @underdark I have edited the question

Comment: @xachu4u I reproduced the error by stopping selected database. (Could you check whether database("testqgis"?) is alive?)

Comment: @sanak I also thought of that. But how can i make sure it is connected? I opened DB Manager, kept the table and database in opened state and tried. No change in error!

Comment: OK i have noticed something, the actual db name in pgADMIN is 'azx'. In QGIS DB manager, the name shown is 'testqgis'. i don't know how it came up. How can i add a new database. Even pgrouting layer shows only 'testgqis' in the drop down list.

Comment: don't bother answering about the prev comment. I got the answer. Still stuck at the connection thing though

Comment: I have found the mistake i have been making.
When i added the database in Qgis, **i did not save the username and password**, so there was always a connection failure.