# PGRouting Layer plugin "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'db' referenced before assignment"

Tags: pgrouting, qgis-2, unboundlocalerror

I am trying to do some basic computations using the PGRouting plugin for QGIS, but I am getting this error all time:

```
An error has occured while executing Python code:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Gonzalo/.qgis2/python/plugins\pgRoutingLayer\pgRoutingLayer.py", line 407, in run
    if db and db.con:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'db' referenced before assignment

Python version:
2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]


QGIS version:
2.2.0-Valmiera Valmiera, c3a2817

Python path: ['C:/Users/Gonzalo/.qgis2/python/plugins\\processing', 'C:/PROGRA~1/QGISVA~1/apps/qgis/./python', u'C:/Users/Gonzalo/.qgis2/python', u'C:/Users/Gonzalo/.qgis2/python/plugins', 'C:/PROGRA~1/QGISVA~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISVA~1\\bin\\python27.zip', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISVA~1\\apps\\Python27\\DLLs', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISVA~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISVA~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISVA~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISVA~1\\bin', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISVA~1\\apps\\Python27', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISVA~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISVA~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\PIL', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISVA~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISVA~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISVA~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISVA~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Shapely-1.2.18-py2.7-win-amd64.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISVA~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\six-1.3.0-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISVA~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\wx-2.8-msw-unicode', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISVA~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\xlrd-0.9.2-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISVA~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\xlwt-0.7.5-py2.7.egg', '.', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISVA~1\\apps\\qgis\\python\\plugins\\fTools\\tools']
```

I made a local installation of postgres 9.3.4, later I added postgis using the stack builder, and finally I followed the instructions posted here: [PGRouting 2.0 for windows](http://anitagraser.com/2013/07/06/pgrouting-2-0-for-windows-quick-guide/). I also installed python-psycopg2 for my version of python.

The SQL query runs well in pgAdminIII, but I can not make that QGIS plugin work.

Comment: I have seen this kind of error at the different post. Could you check the user name and password are saved at creating connection time ? http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/87111/unable-to-implement-pgroutingplugin-pgr-astar-routing-algorithm-shortest-path/87115?noredirect=1#comment121689_87115

Comment: Dear sanak, your answer has solved my problem. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

In order to make the plugin work, I needed to save both my username and password on the database connection.