# Unable to use pgRouting Layer QGIS plugin with osm2po tool (database connection error)

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting, osm2po

By following these amazing tutorials of Anita Graser [An osm2po Quick Start](https://anitagraser.com/2011/12/15/an-osm2po-quickstart/) and [pgRouting on OSM using osm2po](https://anitagraser.com/2011/12/18/osm2po-part-2-pgrouting-on-osm-the-easy-way/), I was able to use osm2po tool successfully on Windows 7 (x64) with PostgreSQL version 9.5 and pgRouting version 2.1.0. I successfully generated .sql file (at_2po_4pgr.sql), imported the same into my postgres routing DB and then installed QGIS pgRouting Layer plugin through Plugins Manager. Now, I am trying to test pgr_djikstra algorithm using pgRouting Layer plugin but I am running into problem during this last step of the above mentioned tutorial.

I am already connected to my postgres DB through DB Manager of QGIS but in my pgRouting Layer dialogue box, I am never "shown as connected" to my postgres DB as shown in following figure. I tried to press refresh button and drop down list many times but no use.

[image: Screen shot of pgRouting Layer DB connectivity problem]

The problem seems to be with database connection through Python. Because, whenever I try to run 'dijkstra' algorithm (just wanted to give it a try anyways) I am getting a Python execution error as shown below. It shows db connection problem in pgRouting python executable file (which is in pgRouting Layer plugin directory). Following are the screen shots of errors I am getting.

[image: Error_screen_shot1]

[image: Error_screen_shot2]

Although, Python2.7 is the default version and its already added to my system path (in environment variables).

Do I need to modify the indicated python file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, thanks to the previous relevant posts at GIS-SE: [pgRouting Layer Plugin Db error](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/92216/pgrouting-layer-plugin-unboundlocalerror-local-variable-db-referenced-before) and [unable to implement pgRouting Layer plugin](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/87111/unable-to-implement-pgroutingplugin-pgr-astar-routing-algorithm-shortest-path/87115?noredirect=1#comment121689_87115) I figured out my mistake by myself. When I connected to my postgres db through QGIS DB Manager, I did not save username and password which was a mistake and resulted in db connection failure every time.

I have saved username and password and now able to use pgRouting Layer Plugin flawlessly! :)

Comment: You should mark your answer as winning :)